# How to autofill a textbox with a data coming from php , not saved by cookie

Tags: html, jquery

How do I autofill a textbox with data coming from php, not saved by a cookie and not in autocomplete in jQuery?

For example : If I type 'P' in textbox ,then corresponding data 'Prince' is taken from php must be auto filled in textbox with only 'P' in black color and other 'rince' will be faded.

Here the cursor will be in after 'P' and before 'rince'. If I move the cursor to right corresponding data 'Prince' will needed to be black color. If I typed second letter that is 'Po' then new corresponding data 'Pond' will be autofilled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that I'm using on a site I am currently developing. This particular solution is basic and could be extended further.

The idea is to create a 'clone' input, which we place underneath the original input field. We then give the original input a transparent background so that any suggestions from the clone can be seen underneath.

For the sake of speed, it's best to have the data set in Javascript array, or object, which could be set when the page loads using AJAX.

http://jsfiddle.net/2AkmG/

Answer (score 0):

The data needs to either come from a database, a text file, or be hard-coded into the php program.

Comment: Yes, Data must queried from mysql through php to textbox .That part okay for me . I don't know how implement in autofill .

Comment: @Jusnit: You need to use Javascript for that part (since what you want is a dynamic client side change).

Comment: @Bryan It's name  of users ,Users list is saved in database.

Comment: @Andrew , yes it can take users name from DB  pass to javascript by jquery ajax.I can able  to fill name in textbox. But I cant implement this portion  "  only 'P' in black color and other 'rince' will be faded. Here the cursor will be in after 'P' and before 'rince'. If I move the cursor to right corresponding data 'Prince' will needed to be black color . If I typed second letter that is 'Po' then new corresponding data 'Pond' will be autofilled  "

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery ui -autocompete 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: I don't want in auto complete in jquery

Comment: @Jusnit: You need to use Javascript for that part (since what you want is a dynamic client side change).

Comment: @Dezigo Its best way, but client needs in other way.